# Recursive sequence relationship with repeating nested radicals

Tags: recursion, nested-radicals

Here I'd like to introduce:

$6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{6}}}}$

If continuing the pattern indefinitely, the limit is $4$. The values are successively higher and lower than $4$.

In a recursive operation, this would be:

$a(n+1)=6-\sqrt{a(n)}$, with $a(1)=6-\sqrt6$.

How to find $a(n)$ in a compact form?

Comment: Is there a reason to believe that such a form is known? As far as I know, general forms for finite nested radicals are quite difficult to find.

Comment: I spent some time in the past hour investigating this form. I derived a family of values, t(m)=m^2+m to be the integer (replacing 6 in this example) and the limit would thus be m^2. Putting an outer square root over the entire expression would net the natural numbers for the limits.

Comment: Yes, the limit is nice, but I doubt a closed form for the finite case is known.

Comment: I am not good with generating functions. I think this might be one good way in finding a(n). The problem appears simple enough to invoke that and smoothly obtain the answer.

Comment: Among this type of recursion equations, only compact form I know is $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n + 2}$ This can be solved by substituting $a_n$ with $e^x + e^{-x}$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that the limit of the sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3,\cdots$ is equal to the infinite nested radical you wrote at the beginning. It completely depends on how we define "infinite nested radicals", and I do not know anything about them. But I can show you that the recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=6-\sqrt{a_n},\quad a_1=6-\sqrt{6}$ defines a convergent sequence. I'll give you the outline of my solution with some missing details. Please let me know if anything is not clear.

First, note that $a_1\lt 4$ (and $a_2\gt 4$).Then, assuming $a_n\lt 4$ we can deduce that $a_{n+1}>4$ and $a_{n+2}<4.$ By mathematical induction, this is true for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+.$

Also, the above result shows that we should look at the subsequences of odd and even indices separately. In this direction, it would be helpful to notice that $$a_{n+2}=6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{a_n}}.$$ Now, it is an easy exercise to deduce $a_{n+4}\lessgtr a_{n+2}$ provided that $a_{n+2}\lessgtr a_{n},$ where $\lessgtr$ means one inequality at a time. Since
$$a_1\approx3.5505, \qquad a_2\approx 4.1157, \qquad a_3\approx 3.9712, \qquad, a_4\approx 4.0071,$$ by mathematical induction we can claim that the subsequence of odd indices is increasing while the subsequence of even indices is decreasing.

By the Monotone convergent theorem, both subsequences are convergent but may have different limits. Those limits are given by the real-valued solutions to the equation $$x=6-\sqrt{6-\sqrt{x}}.$$ Guess what, the only real solution to this equation is $x=4.$

Comment: Bumblebee, close to the answer for the limit, but i wish to obtain a(n).

Let's say for the general form, and I'll alter slightly here to have a square root over the entire expression (doesn't alter result, just like this form more as if starting with a different form to begin with):

Let's suppose m is the limit for sqrt(m^2+m-sqrt(m^2+m-sqrt(...))) then squaring each side:

m^2=m^2+m-sqrt(m^2+m-sqrt(...))
-m=-sqrt(m^2+m-sqrt(...))
m=sqrt(m^2+m-sqrt(...))

Being m is the same as the expression on right of the topmost expression, by deduction m is the limit.

Comment: Side-note: since m is the limit when the number is of the form m^2+m, when we have a sqrt of the entire expression first presented, we end up with a paradox when m^2+m=1 which one would think would yield phi-1 as the limit but would in fact be zero.

Comment: Apparently m must be greater than or equal to 1 or m^2+m must be greater than or equal to 2.  Let's focus on obtaining a closed form expression for a(n).